# PayPal JavaScript SDK button opens about:blank#blocked window in Django template but not in local HTML file

Tags: javascript, django, paypal

I've been trying to integrate PayPal buttons on my Django website, but I keep having this problem where the PayPal popup window appears as about:blank#blocked. I can see this error in console:

```
popup_open_error_iframe_fallback 
{err: 'n: Can not open popup window - blocked\n    at Ie (…owser=false&allowBillingPayments=true:1342:297830', timestamp: '1644780862712', referer: 'www.sandbox.paypal.com', sdkCorrelationID: 'f12370135a997', sessionID: 'uid_d36969c1b2_mtk6mja6mzy', …}
```

What I don't understand is that the problem isn't there if I just open the HTML file itself in a browser... The script looks like this:

```
<!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
<div id="paypal-button-container" class='text-center mt-2'></div>

<!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=blahblahmyid&currency=EUR"></script>

<script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({
        locale: 'it_IT',
        style: {
            color: 'gold',
            shape: 'rect',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'pay'
        },

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '88.44'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

What's the problem ? I don't understand.

Answer (score 20):

There's a new feature in django 4.0 that follows the addition of the COOP header in newer browsers which, as I understand it, stops remote sites from opening a window in the same browsing context.

The default setting of **SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY** in django isolates the browsing context to just the current document origin. Setting it to **same-origin-allow-popups** allows the paypal popup to open in the current context.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/middleware/#cross-origin-opener-policy

TLDR; set SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY='same-origin-allow-popups'

Comment: Note: there is a debug option to the client.js inclusion which I hadn't noticed before that gives some more hints about errors. e.g.  https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD&debug=true

Comment: Oh man !! Thank you so much !! This fixed the problem !

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed! I'm trying to integrate the Open Money payment gateway in my Django application then showed a blocked popup. I added `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY='same-origin-allow-popups'` in settings.py then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 9):

For django 4.0 settings.py add

SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY='same-origin-allow-popups'

Answer (score 0):

Even for Joomla! 4 it's necessary to set the:
System Http-header plugin
to Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy  => same-origin-allow-popups

Otherwise the SDK paypal pop up will not work with error popup_open_error_iframe_fallback

Comment: There is no coding involved. Just set the joomla 4 plugin properly.